# Redirecting to the same route /user/{{username}} Laravel 4+

Tags: php, redirect, parameters, laravel

I am newbie who wants to make before filter which will check what I want and return redirect with error or success to the same `/user/{{username}}` profile.

So here is my filter before function

```
Route::filter('test', function()
{

     $param = Request::segment(2);

        if($para = 'username')
        {
        Session::flash('error', 'blabla!'); 
        return Redirect::route('profile-public');
        }
            else
            {
                Session::flash('secces', 'xxx!');
                return Redirect::route('profile-public');   
            }

});
```

here is my route

> Route::group(array('before' => 'test'), function()
>   {
>
> Route::get('/user/{username}', array('as' => 'profile-public','uses' => 'ProfileController@user'));
>   });

and my ProfileController public function

```
public function user($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', '=', $username);
    if($user->count()){
        $user = $user->first();
    return View::make('profile.user')
            ->with('user', $user);
    }

    return App::abort(404);
}
```

So my problem is how to get those redirection work, I tried to search google etc and I could not find any answers. Sorry for the mess in the post it's my first post here and sorry for my english.
Example go to public profile of /user/admin --> filter check --> redirect to /user/admin with error or success.

Comment: There is an infinite loop, your filter redirect to profile-public route again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a redirect here, just use this filter :

```
Route::filter('test', function()
{
    $param = Request::segment(2);

    if ($para = 'username')
    {
        Session::flash('error', 'blabla!');
    }
    else
    {
        Session::flash('secces', 'xxx!');
    }
});
```